# How do ggplot2 arguments work?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R with `ggplot2`, these two lines seem to do the same thing:

```
qplot(data=diamonds, carat, price)
qplot(data=diamonds, get("carat"), get("price"))
```

but I don't understand how they work...

How does R understand what `carat` refers to in the first case and what `get("carat")` refers to in the second? If I just try to access `carat` or `get("carat")` on their own I get (unsurprisingly)

```
> carat
Error: object 'carat' not found
> get("carat")
Error in get("carat") : object 'carat' not found
```

Under the hood, how does `ggplot2` set up the bindings such that these elegant calling semantics "just work" and more specifically, how would I go about implementing this sort thing myself? I've tried to read the source but am having trouble understanding it.

Comment: It's not R that can interpret the arguments like that, but `ggplot2`.  Its sorta Hadley magic, but you can look at the function `.()` from `plyr` as well as `as.quoted` to try to understand more.  The quick and dirty answer is that `ggplot` calls do something similar to `attach`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your second example is no different from `qplot(data=diamonds, diamonds$carat, diamonds$price)`, except your version has a higher WTF quotient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hadley, the creator of ggplot2, has a wonderful entry on the devtools wiki about building your own version of the `subset` function--which takes a data argument as well. I learned a whole lot reading it, and I'd be willing to bet the mechanics built up in the article are very similar to what `ggplot` does.

https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Evaluation

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much exactly how ggplot2 works too. Although back then I didn't know as much, so it's not implemented quite as well.

Comment: That sure answers that question completely, thanks for the pointer! :)